# Assembly: How to use the segment selector in win7x64? JMP FAR or CALL FAR in x64 in protected mode

Tags: windows, assembly, operating-system, x86-64, gdt

I know how the 32-bit protected mode implements the jump by modifying the segment selector, but the 64-bit situation is different from what I imagined.

I wrote the descriptor in gdt.[they are both same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4raJ.png)

I wrote a code segment descriptor where the selector is 0x3b, and its properties are exactly the same as the default 0x23 selector.

It fails when I access with jmp far: 0x3b: effective address.[before step into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb5Lh.jpg) [after stepinto:false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDWWL.jpg)

But when I use jmp far 0x23:effective address it succeeds.[sucess use 0x23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW0n5.jpg)

This question has always confused me.
My mechiane information is win7 x64.

I jumped to the address of the ring3 program segment, which is a legal address.

My question is why is this failing? There is no problem doing this on XP-32, why does win764 fail. How to jump correctly.

Comment: Check the GDT's limit.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows does not modify the GDT entry?

Comment: @MartinRosenau After the program ended, I observed it, and it has not been modified

Comment: @CHAOSYD I'm not sure if Windows changes the GDT using `LGDT` during task switches for some reasons...